# Heroku deployed app with Sendgrid errors without log info

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sendgrid

My app has a contact page where users can input their name/email/subject/content and send me a message. I'm using the Sendgrid addon to heroku and think I've done almost everything right. I've got this in my

emails_controller.rb

```
if @email.save
  ContactMailer.contact_message(@email).deliver
  flash.now[:success] = "Your email has sent! I'll try to get back to you shortly."
  render :new
else
  flash.now[:error] = "Please correct the highlighted errors and try again."
  render :new
end
```

(the idea here is to keep a record of each email and also send it to me).

My config/initializers/mail.rb

```
# SendGrid Settings
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'myappname.com'
}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Then, for good measure, following what someone else did in a sendgrid support question. config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myappname.com' }
```

My contact_email.html.erb:

```
class Contact < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "unimportant@example.com"

  def contact_message(email)
    @name = email.name
    @address = email.address
    @subject = email.subject
    @content = email.content
    mail(:to => ENV['EMAIL_ADDRESS'], :subject => @subject)
  end

end
```

I added all the necessary environmental variables through

```
heroku config:add EMAIL_ADDRESS=blah@blah.com
heroku config:add SENDGRID_USERNAME=blah
```

When I push to heroku and try to send myself an email, though, it gives me the "We're sorry. Something went wrong" screen of death, and the logs are (to my eyes) totally useless.

Here's the log starting from when I last pushed to heroku and tried to send myself an email. Any ideas what's possibly going wrong?

```
2013-02-03T20:34:18+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=<appname>-2591.herokuapp.com fwd=69.181.104.85 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=7ms service=201ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-02-03T20:34:18+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-cd9c41b78562d03bb04bcaaa585b31e8.js host=<appname>-2591.herokuapp.com fwd=69.181.104.85 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=125507
2013-02-03T20:34:19+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/pig3-b2d5155bd2811a87cafec6a447459580.png host=<appname>-2591.herokuapp.com fwd=69.181.104.85 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=3010
2013-02-03T20:34:19+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/github-e8c3b3f49b0cc737afe9b3cd6e9ab159.png host=<appname>-2591.herokuapp.com fwd=69.181.104.85 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=3687
2013-02-03T20:34:19+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/odesk2-38dadc2e6b0e94aa6c6766df301716bc.png host=<appname>-2591.herokuapp.com fwd=69.181.104.85 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=1ms connect=2ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=3932
2013-02-03T20:34:19+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/star-02718a47b29575c2d7a0e75ac8bebf4d.png host=<appname>-2591.herokuapp.com fwd=69.181.104.85 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=3104
2013-02-03T20:34:19+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/empty_star-9bf002077eafec40cf239068f7d4d1ca.png host=<appname>-2591.herokuapp.com fwd=69.181.104.85 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=43ms status=200 bytes=3072
2013-02-03T20:34:23+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/emails/new host=<appname>-2591.herokuapp.com fwd=69.181.104.85 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=119ms status=200 bytes=3022
2013-02-03T20:34:23+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-74fd2354261a1131b26861b47bef1d87.css host=<appname>-2591.herokuapp.com fwd=69.181.104.85 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-02-03T20:34:19+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/headshot-767c8913c7af4fc97cb8e15881884f0e.png host=<appname>-2591.herokuapp.com fwd=69.181.104.85 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=4ms connect=6ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=146892
2013-02-03T20:34:39+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/emails host=<appname>-2591.herokuapp.com fwd=69.181.104.85 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=7ms service=131ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-02-03T20:34:39+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=<appname>-2591.herokuapp.com fwd=69.181.104.85 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=1ms connect=3ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=0
```

Also, I DID add Sendgrid (followed Heroku's instructions), and the Sendgrid user interface shows no emails sent. And the last time I tried this, the following line seemed to be the only one in the heroku logs that was relevantly timestamped when I tried to send another message. Not very helpful:

```
2013-02-04T18:15:45+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/contact host=myappname.com fwd=69.181.104.85 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=334ms status=200 bytes=3695
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not showing up on your SendGrid dashboard, my guess would be that your credentials are wrong in the app.  If you type `heroku config` do you see that `SENDGRID_USERNAME` and `SENDGRID_PASSWORD` are set correctly?

Also, you might want to try setting delivery errors to display in your config file.

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Comment: Just added that last line. I'm 100% the username is accurate, and a Sendgrid password was there without my adding anything (and, for some reason, Sendgrid's dashboard says I don't have access to my Account details), so I'm assuming that's correct. I'll try again with that line and see if it raises any interesting errors. Thanks!

Comment: YES! Your first suggestion was dead on. For some reason, that password was off, and though I couldn't (and still can't) access my Account Settings, I was able to reset the password and change it to something else. When I did so, the email sent like magic. (Forgot to check til just now, thus the delayed update). Thanks!

Comment: Cool.  If you want to access the SendGrid dashboard, you'll probably want to sign up for a SendGrid account through the main website.  Glad you got things solved!

Answer (score 0):

Just for a bit of clarification, you can't access the Account Settings on the SendGrid site because Heroku has locked it down. You adjust those same settings from the Heroku interface directly.